# Where does this support reaction come from?

Tags: statics

I am looking at part a of the following question,
[image]

and I can not figure out where this support reaction N is coming from. The solution is as follows.
[image]

The question and diagram make no mention of N. My understanding of the question is that there are three forces acting on the object, gravity and the two tensile forces from the cable. Where does N come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N is just the force of the particle resting on the smooth surface (the shaded thing in Figure 3). The pulleys aren't directly above the particle so it's leaning on the surface. This is also stated in part (c) of the question.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about the normal force.